# Wix:Is it possible to remove the bundle entry from the "Add/Remove programs" in control panel？

Tags: wix, wixsharp

If the installer is built by "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects", no matter I run the Setup.exe or Setup.msi to install my program, the "Add/Remove programs" in control panel will add only one item to manage my program.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects

But if the installer is built by Wix and the Setup.exe is built by "Bootstrapper.Bundle", when I run the Setup.exe to install my program, the "Add/Remove programs" in control panel will add two items. One is associate with the "Bootstrapper.Bundle". Another one is associate with the "MsiPackage" in the Bundle.

Is possible to let the Setup.exe which is built by Wix only add one item to the "control panel Add/Remove programs" the same as it built by "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects"？

Comment: Setting the `ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT` property to `1` in an MSI package will prevent the application from being displayed in the Add or Remove Programs list of Control Panel. In Burn markup there is a field called "Visible" for the `MsiPackage` element - I believe setting `Visible="no"` should add the above construct to the property table of the MSI involved. The bundle itself will show up in add / remove I think. Please test, I haven't used this in a while.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Set the Visible to "no" and it will work.